# How to iterate with enumeration using rayon?

Tags: multithreading, for-loop, rust, iterator, rayon

I can iterate and process both index and the variable within such as:

```
let x = vec![5, 6, 7, 8];

for (index, val) in x.iter().enumerate() {
    println!("{} {}", val, index);
}
```

Now with rayon, from what I know, parallel iteration through `par_iter()` doesn't support enumerate because it has `ParallelIterator`.

Rayon seem to have `IndexedParallelIterator`, but I am not sure how to use it to produce similar result as the simple for loop shown above.

Is there anyway to keep track of the index of each value when parallel iterating? How would the simple for loop look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a [`ParallelIterator`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.0/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html) from a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) by calling [`par_iter()`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.0/rayon/iter/trait.IntoParallelRefIterator.html#tymethod.par_iter) it's also simultaneously an [`IndexedParallelIterator`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.0/rayon/iter/trait.IndexedParallelIterator.html) so you can call [`enumerate()`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.0/rayon/iter/trait.IndexedParallelIterator.html#method.enumerate) on it to get the item indexes like so:

```rust
// rayon = "1.5"
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let x = vec![5, 6, 7, 8];
    x.par_iter().enumerate().for_each(|(index, val)| {
        println!("{} {}", val, index);
    });
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7b3aa916b48204fbe3caea23777b6f53)